# Python Indentation error to match the outer indentation level

Tags: python

I have the following python code.

```
import subprocess, process_utility

class PhantomasProcessor:

    def run_test(self, url):
    """
    Method to run a test through Phantomas.

    Args:
        url for which you want to run the test.

    Returns:
         The json output for 
     """

    command = "phantomas " + url + "--har=test.har"
    result = ProcessUtility.execute_command(command)
    return result

def main():
phantomas_processor = PhantomasProcessor()
print phantomas_processor.run_test("www.amazon.com")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Upon execution I get the error.

`IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`.

I have matched the outer indentation level, but then why do I still keep getting this error.

Comment: make sure you are not mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: It works for me. Is this your complete code ?

Comment: I have a main class too . edited the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python unlike many other languages the indentation of the code matters. In your case you missed to indent the content of the class declaration:

import subprocess, process_utility

```
class PhantomasProcessor:

    def run_test(self, url):
        """
        Method to run a test through Phantomas.

        Args:
             url for which you want to run the test.

        Returns:

             The json output for 
        """

        command = "phantomas " + url + "--har=test.har"
        result = execute_command(command)
        return result
```

Comment: Then you should check if you accidentally mixed tabs and spaces.

Comment: No I did not I checked that.

Answer (score 1):

Your def and all the lines below should be moved to the right by one indent (4 spaces  / 1 tab / whatever you are using)

Comment: I have edited the question. I tried the same but still am getting this error

Comment: The lines below `def run_test` are still too far to the left

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
import subprocess, process_utility

class PhantomasProcessor:

    def run_test(self, url):
    """
    Method to run a test through Phantomas.

    Args:
        url for which you want to run the test.

    Returns:
         The json output for 
     """

    command = "phantomas " + url + "--har=test.har"
    result = ProcessUtility.execute_command(command)
    return result

def main():
    phantomas_processor = PhantomasProcessor()
    print phantomas_processor.run_test("www.amazon.com")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent as follows:

```
import subprocess, process_utility

class PhantomasProcessor:

    def run_test(self, url):
        """
        Method to run a test through Phantomas.

        Args:
            url for which you want to run the test.

        Returns:
            The json output for 
        """

        command = "phantomas " + url + "--har=test.har"
        result = ProcessUtility.execute_command(command)
        return result

def main():
    phantomas_processor = PhantomasProcessor()
    print phantomas_processor.run_test("www.amazon.com")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```